# How to annotate an existing queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to update a queryset with an annotation in class based view.

Why does this work:

```
def get_queryset(self):
   qs = self.model._default_manager.all().annotate(admin_roles_count=Count('administrators'))
   return qs
```

But this does not?:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    qs.annotate(admin_roles_count=Count('administrators'))
    return qs
```

`print(qs[0].admin_roles_count)` throws:

```
AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'admin_roles_count'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because each time when you call the `annotate(...)` a new Queryset object is created and returned. So, you need to update the function as

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    qs = qs.annotate(admin_roles_count=Count('administrators'))
   ^^^^^^^^
    return qs
```

This is because of the ***[lazy loading of QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)***

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the difference in your code and my example...?

Comment: bolded the difference.

Comment: Thanks! This works. However in my case `administrators` is a M2M field and the qs 
 annotation appears to pick up all M2M relationships, not just those on the object. Could this error be related?

Comment: Do you know why it might be the case?